# Bullet-proofing asset pipeline specs in Rails (5.2) - how force test failure if ANY model.css or model.coffee is missing from asset pipie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is there a way, in Rspec, to force a failure if **any** of the "Rails better find this file or else" assets are missing?

In production, the app fails with the exception `ActionView::Template::Error: The asset "foo.css" is not present in the asset pipeline`

That's because the file is missing, because it would be blank, because it's for a rarely viewed backend model.

Sure, I could add a quick spec or two to "hit" the page. (In theory a simple "view" spec won't work, unless you *also* render the template, and the layout, which is extra complex when devise authentication is involved.)

But what I want is for Rspec is simple: to automatically fail with "model.css is missing from the asset pipelines" whether or not there is a spec in place to "hit" that asset.

Whenever possible we simply want the app to fail, hard, right in Test if it's going to do that anyway on Production... that kind of being the point of test.

None of the following worked when added to `test.rb`:

```
  config.assets.compile = false / true
  config.assets.digest  = true / false
  config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false / true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true / false
```

This seems like a useful safeguard to avoid situations where specs pass and production throws exceptions because Rails rquires some pointless and empty file that does not exist (and is not declared in the asset pipelines).